# Setting height to 100% of parent element

Tags: html, css

How do I set the height of an element to 100% of its parent element?

In the code below, I am trying to set the height of  `<strong>` to 100%.

The height of its sibling, `<div>` element changes according to the amount of text in it, which thus changes the height of the parent `<li>` element.

Regardless of the the parent `<li>`element, I am looking for the height of `<strong>` element = 100%.

In the Fiddle, the "Description" box should have a height of 100% to create the effect of a single grey strip on the left side of the page.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }  

.course-info {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.course-info li {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
     display: block;
}

.course-info div {
 float: left;
 width: 60%;
}

.course-info strong {
 width: 35%;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 background: #f4f4f4;
 color: #888;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
 
     <ul class="course-info">
     
     
     <li><strong>Description </strong> 
   <div>Text here. The amount of text here varies. As it increases, the strong element on the left should increase to fill the parent li element.</div></li>
    
     <li><strong>Participants max.</strong><div>Learn basic conversation</div></li>
    
     <li><strong>Number of sessions</strong><div>5 Persons</div></li>
   
  </ul>
```

Comment: What you are building here is a table. You should just use the element `<table>` which has built in support for what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily by converting this from a `<ul>` to a `<table>` which natively supports what you are trying to do.

user [misterManSam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2930477/mistermansam) provided the `<table>` version of this answer in [this jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/sumino/1/edit?html,css,output) in the comments below

---

To do this using your current setup you can do the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/4tjama61/

CSS

```
.course-info li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position:relative; /* no float, add position relative */
}

.course-info div {
    margin-left:35%; /* margin-left instead of floating */
    width: 60%;
}

.course-info strong {
    width: 35%;
    display: block;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    color: #888;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute; /* absolute position. No floats. positions relative to parent li */
}
```

Floated elements and `height:100%` do not play nice together as floats are removed from the normal document flow. The same effect can be achieved (as in the provided example) with absolute positioned elements mixed with margin-left

Comment: [I created this in a table](http://jsbin.com/sumino/1/edit?html,css,output) if you want to add it to your answer :) It's the correct solution.